# IndexOutOfRangeException error

Tags: java, exception, decimal

The code compiles fine but gives run time errors like

```
      Exception in thread "main" BitBin.IndexOutOfRangeException: out of range
                 at BitBin.decmalToBinary.birBin(decmalToBinary.java:52) 
                 at BitBin.decmalToBinary.main(decmalToBinary.java:42)
```

I'm not really sure what the issues are as I have thrown the exceptions in the code which are as follows:
sorry i want when I enter any thing except numbers it has exception for me, can you help me? for example i enter chars instead of number

```
package BitBin;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class decimalToBinary {

   static int decToBin (int n) {
             int term = 0;

            while (n != 0) {
                term ++;
                n /= 2;
        }

            return term;
    }

       static String ArrayBinToStr (int[] Array) {
            String ret = "";
            for (int i = Array.length-1; i >= 0; i--)
                  ret += Integer.toString(Array[i]);

        return ret;
    }

             public static void main (String[] args) {


                    Scanner sc=new Scanner (System.in);
                       System.out.print ("Enter number : ");
                       int num = sc.nextInt();

                         int[] bin = new int[decToBin (num)];
                          int dup = num, el = -1;

                   while (dup != 0) {
                         int rem = dup % 2;
                         bin [++el] = rem;
                            dup /= 2;
        }

                      String d2b = binBit(bin);
                             System.out.println("Binary of " + num + " is: " + d2b);


    }
                  static  String binBit(int []d2b) throws IndexOutOfRangeException{
                        Scanner sc=new Scanner (System.in);
                          System.out.print ("Enter bit: ");
                        int bit = sc.nextInt();
                        if(bit>d2b.length-1 || bit<0)
                            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("out of range");
                         String rit="";
                          int i=bit;
                          if(d2b[i]== 0  )
                                  System.out.println("bite " +i+ " om  0 ast.");
                        else
                           System.out.println("bite " +i+ " om 1 ast.");
                            for (i = d2b.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
                           rit+=Integer.toBinaryString(d2b[i]);
}

                        return rit;


    }

}
}


SAMPLE INPUT FILE
Enter number: 
Enter bit:
```

Comment: Where are lines 42 and 52?

Comment: please help me it doest have errors

Comment: Can you make your code organised??

Comment: line 52 is: throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("out of range");

Comment: @Kezz101 : line 42 is: String d2b = binBit(bin);

Comment: @prasanth : what do you mean?

Comment: how can i organised my code?

Comment: Where does the class start? What is the name of the class?? I'm finding some statements after main method, what are those??

Comment: @honey you are the one throwing the exception here `                        if(bit>d2b.length-1 || bit<0)
                            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("out of range");`

Comment: how can i change it matt?

Comment: the class statrs from public class decimalToBinary { , after main ?

Answer (score 0):

`if(bit>d2b.length-1 || bit<0)` this condition is being true .
So it throws that exception.

String d2b = binBit(bin);

And you are evalutaing inside `binBit(bin)` method `if(bit>d2b.length-1 || bit<0)`. So I think first condition is always being true so it is throwing exception.

Comment: no! for example i enter 9 it has 4 bits when i enter 5th as bit it has error

Answer (score 0):

The exception you're getting is a normal result if the bit you enter is too big for the number.  For example, let's say you enter the "3" for the number.  Then d2b will be the array [1,1], the binary representation of 3. That means you can enter a value of 0 or 1 for the bit. Anything bigger than that and you will get the exception, from the code which checks that condition:

```
if(bit > d2b.length - 1 || bit < 0)
    throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("out of range");
```

I ran your code (with some unimportant variations) with the following inputs and it worked fine!

```
Enter number : 255
Enter bit: 3
bite 3 om 1 ast.
Binary of 255 is: 11111111
```

Does that answer the mystery?

Comment: yes , sorry i want when I enter any thing except numbers it has exception for me, can you help me? for example i enter chars instead of number

Comment: If you enter chars instead of numbers the Scanner will already throw an exception on `nextInt();` Are you saying that you _don't_ want to throw an exception when the requested bit is too big for the array of bits in d2b?